# Setting focus colour of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tvos, collectionview

I am trying to set the colour of the focus state of a UITableViewCell. The issue is i noticed a weird white border around the cell, So I made the tableview background black, and the focus colour black as well, to check if this is indeed the case, and you can see in the screen shot, there is a faint white/gray border around the cell. Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    backgroundView = nil
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    if context.nextFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When transitioning between cells during scroll
[image]

Very faint line outlining the cell
[image: Very faint line outlining the cell]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)
    if context.nextFocusedView === self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work :( If you look at the first screen shot you'll see theres a gray focus color, before turning to black. I think this is what's peaking through. and "looks" like a border.